# Searching for Java class in a package recursively by name

Tags: java, reflection

Is there some easy, well-explored way to search for a given class by name in a package, and, recursively, in all sub-packages of a this package?

I.e. given existing classes, such as:

- `foo.MyClass`
- `foo.bar.baz.some.more.MyClass`
- `foo.bar.baz.some.more.OtherClass`

I'd like to run something like `magicMethod("foo.bar.baz", "MyClass")` and get `Class foo.bar.baz.some.more.MyClass` as result.

Obviously, it's fairly easy to implement manually - by exploring loaded packages from `Package.getPackages()`, filtering whatever's appropriate and seeking for the class in a loop using `Class.forName(...)` - but may be there's something in standard Java libraries or some other widespread libraries, such as Apache Commons, that solve this task?

Comment: The public Java APIs don't offer anything for this. The package is always an integral part of the identity of a class in Java. To my knowledge there is no single API function that accepts or returns a class name separated from it's the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shameless plug for my own OSS software : https://bitbucket.org/stevevls/metapossum-scanner/wiki, available in maven central.

The typical use cases for this library are for doing things like looking for implementing classes like this:

```
Set<Class<? extends MyDiscoverableHelper>> implementingClasses = new ClassesInPackageScanner()
    .findImplementers("com.mypackage.service.impl", MyDiscoverableHelper.class);
```

or annotated class like this:

```
Set<Class> entityClasses = new ClassesInPackageScanner()
    .findAnnotatedClasses("com.mypackage.datamodel", javax.persistence.Entity.class);
```

but the selection strategy can be swapped out by implementing an interface and passing it to the scanner.  If what you're trying to do is find classes by name, the code snippet would look like this:

```
Set<Class> entityClasses = new ClassesInPackageScanner().setResourceNameFilter(new ResourceNameFilter() {
    public boolean acceptResourceName(java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String fileName) {
        return fileName.equals("MyClass.class");
    }
}).scan("foo");
```

I wrote this library a while ago because I never found an implementation that I liked for exploring packages.  There are a number of libraries that have their own internal API, but nothing that I knew of that packaged it up in a nice API.

Plus, exploring the Package(s) is actually tricky to get right.  It's not as straightforward as it may seem at first!

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's viable way to go! Manual exploration of `Packages` proves to be really tricky, that's right...

Comment: excellent...if you do check it out, i'd love to hear any feedback.  i'm probably going to put together a small release sometime soon.  thanks!

Comment: I've checked your package - it worked flawlessly, but we've settled for a mapping of "string ID => Class" for a few other, mainly business-logic related, reasons (we have a couple of other things based on these "string IDs", so we've obliged to use generators). Thanks for your answer and excellent library anyway :)